# How can i list the values of a Node in JSON ?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Say, I have a JSON that has an array of "Topics"
I need to list all "created_at" values of all the topics
without the other data , using the Chrome console

P.S : I'm Using [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the objects in your array and simply access the property `created_at`.

### Example

```
var json = {
    all_topics: [{
        "created_at:" "2016-08-08T10:22:03.123Z",
        "name": "topic1"
    }, {
        "created_at": "2016-08-08T11:43:06.963Z",
        "name": "topic2"
    }]
}

for (var topic of json.all_topics) {
    console.log(topic.created_at);
}
```

You can use `JSON.stringify` to turn a JavaScript object into a JSON String, and `JSON.parse` to turn a JSON string into a JavaScript object.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json); 
==> {"all_topics":[{"created_at":"2016-08-08T10:22:03.123Z","name":"topic1"},{"created_at":"2016-08-08T11:43:06.963Z","name":"topic2"}]}

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
==> Object {all_topics: Array[2]}
```

Alternatively, you could return a new array with the filtered property using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var topics = json.all_topics.map(function(obj){ 
   return obj.created_at;
});

==> ["2016-08-08T10:22:03.123Z", "2016-08-08T11:43:06.963Z"]
```

Comment: Sometimes the JSON values have { " OR ' }, and i can't contain it in variable this way , and it's big JSON !

Comment: @AhmedKamal I've added a bit more detail to my answer, which might clarify things. You need to traverse the parsed JSON in some way to get the property for each item in the array, so the larger the JSON, the longer it will take. If you have other particular issues, please provide some more detail to your question, with examples.